# Why can’t the answer be "artlessness"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

In the following question:

> It is to the novelist's credit that all of the episodes in her novel are presented realistically, without any _____ or playful supernatural tricks.
>
> A) elucidation
>
> B) discrimination
>
> C) artlessness
>
> D) authenticity
>
> E) whimsy

To fill in the blank, I made use of “or,” which means something opposite of supernatural should go into the blank. That's why I chose “C) artlessness,” which also means natural and untrained.

But the answer is “E) whimsy.” Where did I go wrong? What is the author trying to convey?

Comment: What is required is something the opposite of _realistic!_ The author says that the episodes are _without_ [blank].

Comment: It's an answer that a great many native English speakers would have got wrong.

Comment: The blank doesn't really need to be the opposite of supernatural. The conjunction *"or"* doesn't point to the opposite of the condition defined after the *or* or before it.

Comment: @ Dhanishtha Ghosh, thanks for your opinion. Usually until now, I heard that "or" = opposite and "and" = similar

Comment: I think there are very many native speakers, especially these days, who would have absolutely no idea what 'artlessness' is.

Comment: [please correct your question; Why can't the answer be "artlessness"]. Since you are doing what looks like advanced English, you might want to review the basics. And "What is the author trying to convey." **artlessness does not mean natural or untrained**. It means a state or condition lacking artistic merit.

Comment: @Lambie, thanks for pointing out! changed.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, but the main meanings of _artless_ are _lacking in guile_  and _natural, not artificial_  - see [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/artless).

Comment: @KateBunting artless: **lacking art, knowledge or skill, uncultured** in Merriam Webster. In other words, lacking in artistic merit, which is fine for describing a novel. I really do not need English lessons.

Comment: @Lambie Well, OK, Merriam-Webster gives that as the first of three definitions, but most dictionaries give it as the third, as in the link I supplied. I'm not trying to give you English lessons, just pointing out that _artless_ can indeed mean _natural_.

Comment: @KateBunting But the word is artlessness, not artless.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the two noun phrases around “or” should *not* be opposites. We are told the episodes are “presented realistically” and “without [...] playful supernatural tricks” is one example of that, and the only other option that would make sense as another example of that is “without *whimsy*”. It would not make sense to say “without artlessness“ here because that would mean that the episodes were without honesty. (The same is why “authenticity” would not work here either, and the rest of the options just make no sense in context.)

“Or” here is just creating a list. You could reword the sentence and keep approximately the same meaning:

> [...] are presented realistically, *with neither* _____ *nor* playful supernatural tricks.

You could also think of a simpler example:

> She went alone, without her mom or her sister.

It should be obvious here how a mom and a sister are not opposite alternatives but rather are examples of people she went without.

Answer (score -1):

This is a difficult question. I believe that "whimsy" is correct because it is describing "supernatural" along with "playful." If it was "artless" rather than "artlessness," I believe it would be correct.

Comment: "artless" doesn't work at all, as a noun is required here. But I do think "whimsy" is the correct answer, as it is one part of the opposite to "realism"